# need help in recovering my BCH

Tags: bitcoin-cash, segregated-witness

i mistakenly transferred 2.0 BCH from a BTC(blockchain.info) address to a Segwit address(Greenaddress)... I need help in recovering my BCH. I'm will to part with 20% if you can help retrieve it. I'm not really an IT inclined person so i'm ready to send whatever infos needed in retrieving to whoever is willing to help.

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin SE. Please note: NEVER send you private keys / seed phrase to someone who is trying to help you. If you do that, they'll be able to steal your coins.

Comment: thanks for the advise... But i'm clueless on how to go about recovering it.

Comment: segwit is not supported for bitcoin cash! did you move it to bitcoin segwit address?

Comment: yes i moved it to bitcoin segwit address...

Comment: https://www.blocktrail.com/BCC/address/38V1ovQ2sSThDxjt9Bmi3iSY75LZshqobi

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do that easily even if you have the private key Since bitcoin cash doesn't support Segwit, so you have to edit source code and mine that transaction by yourself.

Helpful links:

[Bitcoin Cash SegWit hack](https://medium.com/bitclave/bitcoin-cash-segwit-hack-e82c7029f841)

[Recovering BCH sent to Segwit addresses](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/7eixcu/recovering_bch_sent_to_segwit_addresses/?st=jee4ic5o&sh=11e0ebf5)

Comment: That's a lot to take in for me... I'm not a programmer and i hardly understand coding and stuffs... I don't mind engaging you to have that done for me then i pay you for your service. Some say its risky to give out personal infos but whats the use of the BCH if i cant have access to it???

Comment: stackexchange is not the place to pay for services. please take a look at the links I've attached